# Cisco IPSec VPN: Multiple address ranges for crypto map?

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec

I'm setting up an IPSec VPN using a Cisco router.  The relevant part of the config:

```
crypto map MYVPN 10 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 173.1.2.3
 set transform-set my-transform 
 set pfs group2
 match address 103

access-list 103 permit ip 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63 192.168.77.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 103 permit ip 192.168.77.0 0.0.0.255 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63
access-list 103 permit ip 84.9.206.104 0.0.0.7 192.168.77.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 103 permit ip 192.168.77.0 0.0.0.255 84.9.206.104 0.0.0.7
```

This allows traffic to/from `192.168.77.0/24` behind the peer.  However, I also have another subnet, `192.168.122.0/24` behind the same peer that I would like to allow access.  So I've had to modify my ACL to include `192.168.0.0/16`:

```
access-list 103 permit ip 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
access-list 103 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63
access-list 103 permit ip 84.9.206.104 0.0.0.7 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
access-list 103 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 84.9.206.104 0.0.0.7
```

Ideally, I don't want this large of a range specified.  Is there any way I can specifically configure `192.168.77.0/24` and `192.168.122.0/24`?

Answer (score 0):

Either I missed something or you just add to the existing ACL new network as class C in the same manner, then #clear cry ipsec& clear cry sa to renew the site and it will come up with new encryption domain/net added ...

access-list 103 permit ip 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63 192.168.122.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 103 permit ip 192.168.122.0 0.0.0.255 84.9.208.128 0.0.0.63